# 2013 Paper Wallet Issues

Tags: wallet-recovery, paper-wallet, lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

Thought I made a paper wallet in 2013 with 2 coins, just checked it is showing empty. The blockchain transaction showing unspent as of when I made the wallet in 2013.
I thought it was in the paper wallet so I miss placed my blockchain wallets info. I have wallet ID's but no passwords, 3 wallets trying to narrow down which wallet to try and figure out the password.

Is there a way to figure out what wallet a transaction came from, because I fave a few?? I think the transaction is in limbo- Please help anyone
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you saying they may be in a blockchain wallet, as in an e-wallet on the blockchain.info website?

Comment: Im not really sure, what I did I made a paper wallet but its empty now, if someone stole it is should of been spent, its showing unspent. I thought it was safe in the paper wallet, I misplaced my wallet information. I do have a json file on my computer and a core120.js.. but I dont have my wallet password just these files and I dont know what to do with them if they are useful at all.

Comment: Both those files should be in clear text format. You could open them in a text editor and see if there's anything that looks like a private key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to figure out what wallet a transaction came from, because I fave a few??

No, wallets just hold private keys, and the private key is all you need to spend coins sent to a "normal" bitcoin address starting with a `1`. From the public view, all that can be seen is the address the coins were sent to, there is no more information about that address such as what wallet generated it or where the private key is held.

> I think the transaction is in limbo

If the transaction was confirmed back in 2013, and it is unspent since then, it won't be in limbo, you just need to find the wallet which holds the private key for the address that transaction was sent to :)

I'm afraid there isn't much else anyone here can do to help you, if you have lost the private key then your bitcoins are lost, so I hope you find them in one of your wallets!